# Animate function calls multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have created a simple JavaScript file in which i have 2 images.

here person can either swipe left or right & accordingly images swipes

here is my code,

```
$('#landscapeimage1').swiperight(function (event) { //here lanscapeimage1 is canvas on which i have drawn an image.

    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var slide = "+=" + width + "px";
    $('#landscapeimage').animate({'left': -width}, 1, function () {
        $('#landscapeimage1').animate({"left": slide}, "fast", function () {});
        $('#landscapeimage').animate({"left": slide}, "fast", function () {
            currentImage = getPreviousImage();
            currentCanvas = "landscapeimage";

            drawImage();
            $(this).unbind(event);
            return false;
        });
        return false;
    });

    return false;
});
```

**initially when i swipe it works properly but if i visit same image then it calls same function again & again until unvisited images does not comes & if i have visited all images then it goes to infinite loop.**

i don't understand why this happens.

i have tried to stop animate & unbind swipe function but it also not working.

```
<div data-role="page" id="imagepage">

            <div class="whiteBackground" id="landscapeimage" style="position: relative;">
                <canvas id="image" style="z-index: 1;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;" height="200px" width="200px">
                </canvas>
                </div>

<div class="whiteBackground" id="landscapeimage1" style="position: relative;">
                <canvas id="image1" style="z-index: 1;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;" height="200px" width="200px">
                </canvas>
                </div>

        </div>
```

After debugging i have found that animate function calling multiple times not swipe function but i can't figure out why? please help me out.

does any body know why this happens?

Comment: try 'left': '-' + width + 'px' which might be causing the problem.

Comment: try using `event.stoppropagation()` within `swiperight()`, this would stop any unnecessary events from propagating if any

Comment: Could you replicate the same on jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: by using `stoppropagation()` it stops swipe as well.

Comment: sorry but i don't know how to use jsfiddle.net (like put image and all.)

Comment: even my whole project is to large to so i don't think this should be possible.

Comment: Use event.preventDefault();

Comment: @ParkashKumar i have tried that also. but it also not working.